# tikz - diagram problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

first of all I would like to thank you for this helpful forum. This is my first post here so if I can improve something, just tell it to me for the future :)

I have some troubles with tikz and hope you can help me. The final result should looks like this:

[image]

I dont know how to resize the boxes that they have the same size. I mean the three boxes should be as width as the top boxes. What I have so far:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}
  \tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em}}
  \tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \node [box]                                     (inv)      {0};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of inv]                 (deter)    {1};
    \coordinate [below=0.5cm of deter]              (vuoto1)   {};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of vuoto1]              (meth2)    {2};
    \node [box, left=0.5cm of meth2]                (meth1)    {3};
    \node [box, right=0.5cm of meth2]               (meth3)    {4};   
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of meth1]               (select)   {5};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of select]              (select2)  {6}; 
    \node [box, below=4.5cm of meth2]               (decide)   {7};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of decide]              (inter)    {8};

    \path [line] (inv)      --    (deter);
    \path [line] (deter)    --    (vuoto1);
    \path [line] (vuoto1)   -|    (meth1);
    \path [line] (vuoto1)   -|    (meth2);
    \path [line] (vuoto1)   -|    (meth3);
    \path [line] (meth1)    --    (select);
    \path [line] (select)   --    (select2);
    \path [line] (select2)  --    (decide);
    \path [line] (meth2)    --    (decide);
    \path [line] (meth3)    --    (decide);
    \path [line] (decide)    --    (inter);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can seen the boxes are only as width as the text content.

I would appreciate if you can help me :)

Thanks a lot.

Christine

Comment: Great first question. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an "indirect" approach, where the borders of the widest nodes are drawn separately. I removed `draw,thick` from the `box` style, and added them to a new style `narrowbox`, which include the `box` style and `text width=4cm`. This is used for the five nodes in the center.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\tikzset{
  box/.style={rectangle, text centered, minimum height=3em},
  narrowbox/.style={box,text width=4cm,draw,thick},
  line/.style={draw, thick, -Stealth}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \node [box]                                     (inv)      {Determinate the clustering variables};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of inv]                 (deter)    {Decide the clustering procedure};
    \coordinate [below=0.5cm of deter]              (vuoto1);
    \node [narrowbox, below=0.5cm of vuoto1]        (meth2)    {Partitioning clustering};
    \node [narrowbox, left=0.5cm of meth2]          (meth1)    {Hierarchical clustering};
    \node [narrowbox, right=0.5cm of meth2]         (meth3)    {Graph-based clustering};   
    \node [narrowbox, below=0.5cm of meth1]         (select)   {Select a measure of similarity or dissimilarity};
    \node [narrowbox, below=0.5cm of select]        (select2)  {Choose a clustering algorithm}; 
    \node [box, below=4.5cm of meth2]               (decide)   {Decide the clustering procedure};
    \node [box, below=0.5cm of decide]              (inter)    {Decide the clustering procedure};

    \path [line] (inv)      --    (deter);
    \path [line] (deter)    --    (meth2);
    \path [line] (vuoto1)   -|    (meth1);
    \path [line] (vuoto1)   -|    (meth3);
    \path [line] (meth1)    --    (select);
    \path [line] (select)   --    (select2);
    \path [line] (select2)  --    (select.south |- decide.north);
    \path [line] (meth2)    --    (decide);
    \path [line] (meth3)    --    (meth3.south |- decide.north);
    \path [line] (decide)   --    (inter);

% draw rectangles around top and bottom nodes
\foreach \N in {inv,deter,decide,inter}
   \draw [thick] (\N.north -| meth1.west) rectangle (\N.south -| meth3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Torbjørn, thank you so much for your help. Finally it works! Many thanks.